# Wordpress PHP, is this the same? and why?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
        <?php 
            wp_title('|', 'true', 'right');
            wp_bloginfo('name');
        ?>
```

and

```
        <?php wp_title('|', 'true', 'right'); ?> <?php wp_bloginfo('name'); ?>
```

Greetings! I just wanted to know if these two are the same? If so, what do you call this technique of shortening codes.

Comment: Yes, the code is equivalent and AFAIK there's no name for this other than splitting one code block into two or combining two code blocks into one.

Comment: Nitpicking-mode on: No, they are not the same. He is outputting an extra space of html between `?>` and `<?php`.

Comment: Rik, I came here to say just that. If there are no blankspaces before the first opening tag and wp_bloginfo needs to change the headers, it WILL NOT work the same. The first one will work just fine, the second one will throw a "Headers already sent" warning.

Comment: Hi sir Pedro,

I didn't quite understood your comment about the "Headers already sent" warning. Will the extra space in the middle of the closing and opening of PHP tags cause this? Or the code itself is wrong, thus it will still cause the error even without the space?

Thank you!

Comment: The code **between** is exactly the same, so, no error there. But if you're using header commands in `wp_bloginfo` you will get that error and the header command is ignored. You can't output **anything** before sending all the headers (cookies/locations/cachecontrol/expires etc.). Removing that space thus `?><?php` fixes that. If you'r not using header commands in `wp_bloginfo` there is no issue. (I actually don't know if you would/can output headers in `wp_bloginfo` in WordPress) But better to be safe than sorry.

Comment: Thank you! I am also fairly new to stackoverflow, the community is just plainly awesome!

Thanks everyone for the insights and comments!

Answer (score 1):

Your second piece of code will print out one whitespace character between the outputs of the `wp_title` and `wp_bloginfo`, which may or may not be significant.

`wp_title` and `wp_bloginfo` are functions which output (presumably) the title of the blog and a certain piece of information about it. This isn't really a way to "shortening" code, but you may wish to read up on [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: Thank you! The link to DRY gave me a lot of insights, I'm fairly new to web developing and programming, this is a lot of help.

Comment: Lookup Minification too: [Minification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minification_(programming)) (also minimisation or minimization), in computer programming languages and especially JavaScript, is the process of removing all unnecessary characters from source code, without changing its functionality. These unnecessary characters usually include white space characters, new line characters, comments, and sometimes block delimiters, which are used to add readability to the code but are not required for it to execute.

Comment: Will do sir! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

They are same but first one is more concise. In the 2nd one you are adding an extra pair of  tags.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they're the same.

The only difference is in the code structure (extra tags in the second version), that doesn't change what it does.